# Can't increase IntelliJ memory heap

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory, heap-memory, ram

My intelliJ is running low on memory. I tried allocating more, increasing heap size,...This occurs in the IDEA itself. I constantly get the "This IDE is running on low memory" on launch. but the fix doesnt work.
But when i "Change memory settings" and add a bigger value to the Maximum Heap Size, nothing changes on restart, i am stuck with the default 256m.
I tried adding -Xmx4096 to my Java in the java configuration pannel.
I tried Help>Change memory settings, then change the Maximum heap size value. I changed in Help>Edit Custom VM Options, adding -Xmx4096m as a parameter.
I tried Help>Edit Custom Properties ,adding -Xmx4096m as a parameter

Nothing worked

Comment: Is your IDEA itself running low on memory or your program that you launch from *within* IDEA? Those two require quite different changes and it's not quite clear which one you've attempted. Can you [edit] your question to answer that question (ideally with the exact error message you get) and also **where exactly** you edited **which value**?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the post, adding some precisions

Comment: Enable [IDE memory indicator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html#enable-memory-indicator) and see how much memory was allocated to the IDE. Then you can understand what is the effective value used. Btw what IDE version do you use? Make sure to try latest from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: The memory indicator tells i have 256m max and i use all of it (between 230 and 250, but there is clearly not enough memory) I am using the latest version

Comment: Take a look to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html and to https://coderedirect.com/questions/163461/how-to-increase-the-memory-heap-size-on-intellij-idea

Comment: I already tried all the solutions on both of these posts.

Comment: If issue remains, file a report at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new with screenshot of the error you get and idea.log